# Aligning buttons with different text sizes in horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-button

My problem is concerning the following passage:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtSmall"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:onClick="ChSizeSmall"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_button_layout"
                android:text="a"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:shadowColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:shadowDx="0.6"
                android:shadowDy="0.6"
                android:shadowRadius="0.5"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_margin="2.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtMid"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:onClick="ChSizeMid"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_button_layout"
                android:text="a"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:shadowColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:shadowDx="0.6"
                android:shadowDy="0.6"
                android:shadowRadius="0.5"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_margin="2.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtBig"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:onClick="ChSizeBig"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_button_layout"
                android:text="a"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:shadowColor="#9A9A9A"
                android:shadowDx="0.6"
                android:shadowDy="0.6"
                android:shadowRadius="0.5"    
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_margin="2.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Resulting in the following piece of UI:

[image: example]

I have another two rows that appear perfectly aligned and this one is a troublemaker. Sizes of in-button text are different and should be. Other rows doesn't experiment with these sizes, hence they're all right. I know the problem is with the changing sizes, but I've no idea, how to address that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for the LinearLayout or `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` for each one of the buttons.